# Anchor tag with onclick event handler not working in React

Tags: reactjs

This code doesn`t seem to run.

```
<a href="/blog" onClick={this.props.selectPage} name="blog">Blog</a>
```

If I remove href="/blog" the selectPage function runs and if I remove onClick={this.props.selectPage} it redirects me to /blog. Why is one triggering the other? And how can I work around it?

Comment: why do you need onclick for the <a>?

Comment: Because I need to update a state in the parent component at the same time

Comment: you can do it on a callback but not at the same time.

Comment: or you can do like this <div onclick><a/></div> but it's a huck

Comment: hhmmm...how? <a href="/blog" onClick={()=>this.props.selectPage} name="blog">Blog</a> Same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the parent

```
handleChange() {
 this.setState(({...}), 
 () => window.location.hash = "#/blog";
}
```

and dont use `<a>`, make an element with onChange event

Comment: I did it how you mentioned above..with a div

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not bound correctly in your example. You need to write either:

```
<a href="/blog" onClick={() => this.props.selectPage()} name="blog">Blog</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="/blog" onClick={this.props.selectPage.bind(this)} name="blog">Blog</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn`t work this way and I don`t get it why.